# Match only certain fields from a set

Tags: c++, hash, stl, set

### Background

I am trying to find common sub-strings using hashing, for this I first traverse my first string and create a `set<pair<int,int>>` which holds hash values from two different hash functions for possible sub-strings of length ' l '. Then I traverse over the second string and for sub-strings of length ' l '. I compute the hash pair and check if they exist in the set.

### Issue

I need to find the start of the sub-strings while also making use of the faster look-up times like stl::set provides. I cannot use `distance(set.begin(),set.myValue'sPos)` because the set gets sorted automatically.

### Solution Attempt

1. I thought of creating a structure with `{ Hash val1, Hash val2, startPos}` but then I will not be able to use the find function since startPos of the sub-string from string1 and string2 will be different.
2. I know I can modify the == operator for my struct to use the find function but I'm worried that it will affect its running time?

**(TL;DR - In simpler terms, does modifying the == operation affect the running time of the stl find function)**

Is there any better way to do this?

### Example of the issue

Say my strings are `'abcd' and 'dcfcd'` and the length I am looking for is 2.

In the set - `hash('ab'), hash('bc') and hash('cd')` is inserted. (Each of those is a pair of int, numbers obtained from two diff hash fns).

Then I loop over the second string and check if `hash('dc'), hash('cf'),hash('fc') and hash('cd')` exist in the set.
`hash('cd')` does exist in the set and now I would like to know the positions of 'cd' in both the strings.

For 'dcfcd' it is simple since I can get the value from the loop. But I need to also find position of 'cd' in 'abcd'. If the container didn't sort then I would know that 'cd' is the third element of the container and hence at position 3.

Comment: why do you care what hash function was used? Are you confusing set with unordered_set? Do you have code (with sample input and correct output) that you can post? The last question sounds like "Will doing something have the effect of doing that something?" If you want to know if it changes the big-O time complexity, post some code please.

Comment: Hi, I have added an example code, please let me know if that helps. The actual hash function as such isnt relevant to the problem so I havent included that

Comment: That's not code. What's the desired output? You want to implement operator== to give the output, but you need integers ... and it returns bool. Something's not adding up. Can you post a code block that I can copy and paste into my development environement and see the issue? [mcve]

Comment: I think the example explains it :')

Answer (score 0):

You could use set.find().
As far as I know you will take a performance hit when searching a set for certain objects. There is most likely no way around it with a std::set.

Comment: Any other means other than set would be helpful too